# Composer install project root files from package

Tags: php, frameworks, installation, composer-php

I created a small PHP Framework which I want to install into my projects using composer.

The framework includes some files like index.php and some default nginx.conf that should be mapped to the project root.

Is there a way to tell the package to map its own files outside vendor (to the project root in my case) without having to define these locations in the project composer.json?

As I searched for solutions I was reading about composer/installers and many implementations of custom types but as far as I know, all of them require modifications to the projects composer.json

While working as a magento2 developer I noticed Magento doing exactly what I want using "extra" -> "map" in the package composer.json but the implementation of it is limited to some magento specific package types I think.

Please correct me if I'm just doing bullshit and there is a way better approach for my goal of easily installing a small self created framework trough a composer package. Thank you all!